# Spring basePackageClasses from @ControllerAdvice doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, exception

I have definition

```
@ControllerAdvice(basePackageClasses = MyClass.class)
public class MyClassExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(value = { MultipartException.class, FileUploadBase.FileSizeLimitExceededException.class })
    @ResponseBody
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> maximumFileSizeLimitExceeded(RuntimeException ex, WebRequest request) {

        String bodyOfResponse = "message";
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new RestErrorInfo(ex, bodyOfResponse), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);

    }
}
```

If I have `@ControllerAdvice(basePackageClasses = MyClass.class)` my `ExceptionHandler` doesn't work correct.

If I have just `@ControllerAdvice`my `ExceptionHandler` work correct.

What is the problem? I want to put my `ExceptionHandler` just for class `MyClass`.

Comment: What does it mean "my ExceptionHandler doesn't work correct"?

Comment: Don't catch the exception when I upload a file with a size after my threshold. I received just internal server error. If I remove `basePackageClasses` I recevied the error with my bodyOfResponse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `@Controller` annotation instead of `@ControllerAdvice` because with `@ExceptionHandler` the last one can be used only for all controllers (so without `basePackageClasses = MyClass.class`)

Comment: And how I can catch just exception recevied from MyClass Controller? I don't want to catch all exception with max file size, just exception from MyClass?

Comment: As you did before with @ExceptionHandler:
https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-exceptionhandler-example/

Comment: So, you suggest me to move method of ExceptionHandler in my Controller from MyClass?

Comment: I tried to move ExceptionHandler in my controller same as [here](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc#controller-based-exception-handling) but doesn't work.

Comment: Try to follow the link in previous comment, I suggest you to do: 1) You need to tag your controller and not exception class with @Controller annotation; 2) Move exception method in your Controller; 3) Create your ExceptionClass like a normal excetion class as shown in link

Comment: I did that. But the error it's happen before access my method where the error will be. I set in yml configuration max-file-size and any file with a size after that threshold the spring throw automatically the error and I don't catch from my controller.

Comment: I have annotation @RestController. Can be the reason of problem? Is must to be @Controller?

Comment: `@RestController` = `@Controller` + `@ResponseBody`. Try and you will see :)

Comment: I found the MyController is never accessed. The error with file size is throw before enter in my controller, so exception handler is never used.

Comment: Any solution for catch that?

Comment: That is another problem. You should call your controller.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by adding the package of the handler into springboot scan.

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "your.handler.package")
```

If you are using spring boot, be noticed that by default spring boot only scans beans under the package and sub-package of your bootstrap class.

So if the handler you annotated with @ControllerAdvice is not in any of those packages, you have to add its package into scan manually.